# How to restore the MySQL databases from a corrupted SSD?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, database, data-recovery

My SSD got corrupted. I made a clone of it on an HDD and I have access to *all* original files from `/var/lib/mysql/that_database`.

I want to import `that_database` back, but I can't.

#### What I've tried already

**Copying the database files themselves**

I tried to copy the raw files, and it didn't work: `show tables` works, but queries end with *`that_database.TableName` does not exist*.

**Copying the entire `/var/lib/mysql` directory**

One of the `another_database` and `sys` databases are corrupted. After the files were copied, I tried to restart the server and it cannot start.

```
$ sudo service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
$ systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-04-23 13:50:01 EEST; 2s ago
  Process: 23954 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 23945 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 22245 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

apr 23 13:50:01 notebook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
apr 23 13:50:01 notebook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
apr 23 13:50:01 notebook systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
apr 23 13:50:01 notebook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
apr 23 13:50:01 notebook systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
apr 23 13:50:01 notebook systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

How can I recover this database?

Comment: If you for instance use InnoDB, without the `innodb_file_per_table option` option, rather than MyISAM as the storage engine the data may be stored in the [`system tablespace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_system_tablespace) and not in the files in /var/lib/mysql/that_database

Comment: @HBruijn Yes, I think I use InnoDB. I have all those files, except one database is corrupted. Should I just copy all the files and delete that database which is corrupted?

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: are you using the same my.cnf setting as earlier, i would recommend first take backup of entire database folder and keep it safe then work on restore, post your mysql logs

Comment: I already have a clone of the entire partition. I can try to put the same `my.cnf` if it helps. What logs are you interested about?

Comment: you said mysql fails to start what are you getting in mysql logs

Comment: I posed the output of `systemctl status mysql.service`. Where can I find the logs you want?

Comment: I had this same error message. It was actually an error in the conf file (`key_buffer` needed to be commented and `ft_stopword_file` was missing).